# How to add a new entry box when clicking a button (Python, Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi i want to add a new entry box when clicking a button. How can i do that ?
What've done is im able to "for loop" a group of entry boxes. But i want the entry boxes to appear one by one by clicking a button.

**What've done**

[image]

**My code:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Entry box")
root.geometry("700x500")

my_entries = []

def something():

    entry_list = ''
    for entries in my_entries:
        entry_list = entry_list + str(entries.get()) + '\n'
        my_label.config(text=entry_list)
    print(my_entries[0].get())

for x in range(5):
    my_entry = Entry(root)
    my_entry.grid(row=0, column=x, pady=20, padx=5)
    my_entries.append(my_entry)

my_button = Button(root, text="Click Me!", command=something)
my_button.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=20)
```

Comment: What the problem if you from create a function and make entries inside that?

Comment: I had tried to make a button and it link to the add function whenever i clicked it. However it only show 1 times of the entry box only .

Comment: You just want 5 entries to appear one by one right?

Comment: [link](https://ibb.co/TBRLN0K) here is the link for my code demo

Comment: @CoolCloud yes, when a user click on the button the entry will appear one by one instead of all together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not much of work here, create a variable to keep track of the columns you are inserting the widget into and then just insert it based on that number, like:

```
# Rest of your code..

my_entries = []
count = 0 # To keep track of inserted entries
def add():
    global count
    MAX_NUM = 4 # Maximum number of entries
    if count <= MAX_NUM:
        my_entries.append(Entry(root)) # Create and append to list
        my_entries[-1].grid(row=0,column=count,padx=5) # Place the just created widget
        count += 1 # Increase the count by 1

Button(root, text='Add', command=add).grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10) # A button to call the function
# Rest of your code..
```

Though I am not sure about your other function and its functionality, but it should work after you create entries and then click that button.

Comment: Btw , isit possible to delete one entry box when i press "delete" button?. I had tried to create a delete button and destroy() every widget in it. But everything is gone instead delete one by one

Comment: @ZhuangAh Use the list instead. Ask a new question, answer might be long.